# PlotlyJS rescale yaxis when xaxis range is updated (via rangeslider)

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly

I have the sample chart with range slider created with PlotlyJS:
[image]

It uses API endpoint to fetch data. Now, the slider can be used to change xaxis range like:

[image]

but then the chart looks strange as yaxis has this fixed range and visible data covers only small vertical part of the whole chart.

**Is it possible to scale (change range of) yaxis when xaxis range is updated?**

I tried listening to *plotly_replot* event and then rescaling yaxis, but really couldn't make it work properly.